# Animated Snap.SVG Easing not working

Tags: svg, jquery-animate, snap.svg, jquery-svg

SVG to to animate some stuff and the easing does not seem to be working.

I can use the "bounce" easing and it works fine but the "easeinout" just does nothing it is exactly the same as "linear".

Has anyone encountered this where one will work and another will not? An example of my code is below:

```
whiteCircle.animate({transform: "t250,0,s0,s0"}, 1000, mina.easeinout);
```

AND

```
whiteCircle.animate({transform: "t250,0,s0,s0"}, 1000, mina.bounce);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code (as a minimal testing example showing the problem), ideally on a jsfiddle or jsbin ? The code above looks ok, so wondering if the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: This actually worked! I think because I am moving things quite far and quite quickly the easeinout isn't as visible as on this test I did which may be my issue... https://jsfiddle.net/uu1s04f7/

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was using "easeInOut" with capitals in my actual code rather than "easeinout", also which didn't help was the fact I was moving moving things over large distances quite quickly so the effect was diminished.